# Why I can't use SHA1 before PKCS7.detached in iText7?

Tags: itext, sha1, itext7, pkcs#7

[image]

As the picture show , now I can realize the 1 ,and here is my signed success code , I used

```
pdfSigner.signExternalContainer(iExternalSignatureContainer, estimatedSize);
```

not

```
 pdfSigner.signDetached();
```

:

```
public class PdfSignatureContainerExt implements IExternalSignatureContainer {

private MySignUtil mySignUtil;
public PdfSignatureContainerExt(MySignUtil mySignUtil){
    this.mySignUtil= mySignUtil;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param data , the data to sign
 * @return a container with the signature and other objects, like CRL and OCSP. The container will generally be a PKCS7 one.
 * @throws GeneralSecurityException
 */
@Override
public byte[] sign(InputStream data) throws GeneralSecurityException {

    byte[] dataBytes = streamToBytes(data);
    return  mySignUtil.signP7DetachData(dataBytes);

}

@Override
public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
    signDic.put(PdfName.Filter, PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite);
    signDic.put(PdfName.SubFilter, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);
}}
```

In order to realize the 2 , I altered the code which the output result is invalid:

```
public class PdfSignatureContainerExt implements IExternalSignatureContainer {

private MySignUtil mySignUtil;
public PdfSignatureContainerExt(MySignUtil mySignUtil){
    this.mySignUtil= mySignUtil;
}


@Override
public byte[] sign(InputStream data) throws GeneralSecurityException {

        byte[] dataBytes = streamToBytes(data);
        //change here
        BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
        Security.addProvider(provider);

        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1" , "BC");
        byte[] hash = messageDigest.digest(dataBytes);

        return  mySignUtil.signP7DetachData(hash);      
}

@Override
public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
    signDic.put(PdfName.Filter, PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite);
    //change here
    signDic.put(PdfName.SubFilter, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_sha1);
}}
```

and the output sign result is failed , here is my failed pdf.

[invalid.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vndug51hlclpqi9/invalid.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: SHA-1 is broken. See https://shattered.io No one can use it for signing anymore. Your screen shot is from a mighty old reference. Haven't you seen the PAdES standard or ISO-32000-2 (PDF 2.0) yet? Two of the subfilters in that table are deprecated. They should no longer be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you use to create the **adbe.pkcs7.detached** CMS signature container

```
return  mySignUtil.signP7DetachData(data);
```

(with an `InputStream data`) appears to create the container just like the method you use to create the **adbe.pkcs7.sha1** CMS container

```
return  mySignUtil.signP7DetachData(hash);
```

(with a `byte[] hash`), at least this is what your example file suggests.

This is wrong: As the PDF Reference 1.7 says:

> - **adbe.pkcs7.detached**: No data is encapsulated in the PKCS#7 signed-data field.
> - **adbe.pkcs7.sha1**: The SHA1 digest of the byte range is encapsulated in the PKCS#7 signed-data field with ContentInfo of type Data.

*(section 8.7.2 "Signature Interoperability")*

As you used the equivalent functionality for creating the CMS containers in both cases, you left the *PKCS#7 signed-data field* (by which the optional `eContent` octet string in the CMS `SignedData` field `EncapsulatedContentInfo` is meant) in your **adbe.pkcs7.sha1** container empty which is against the specification.

---

**PS**: Ordinarily I would have referred to the ISO 32000 standards but unfortunately the corresponding sections in both part 1 and part 2 have been changed in a way that makes the content somewhere between even more unclear and outright wrong. Unfortunately that did not cross my mind when one could make inputs for ISO 32000-2.

**PPS**: Ceterum censeo **adbe.pkcs7.sha1** should not be used at all anymore. Our validation code explicitly does not implement validation of these signatures.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . My English have a little poor , so I need to ask more clearly and  I have updated some details. So you mean that in **adbe.pkcs7.sha1** , I shouldn't  just use SHA1 digest the `data` and put it into the the `signP7DetachData()` function , right ? Because it's not meet the standard . But for some reason , I need to do **adbe.pkcs7.sha1** , I mean how I can alter my code ?

Comment: *"So you mean that in **adbe.pkcs7.sha1**, I shouldn't just use SHA1 digest the data and put it into the the `signP7DetachData()` function , right ?"* - Wrong. I mean that your `signP7DetachData()` is not applicable for **adbe.pkcs7.sha1**. So for **adbe.pkcs7.sha1** you have to use the SHA1 digest of the data, but you have to do so differently than it is done in your `signP7DetachData()` methods.